# How to make a multiplied layer become "what you see is what you get"?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layer-style, art

I have black lineart for a drawing multiplied over the drawing itself.  Because I have little foresight, I had simply painted white wherever I wanted to "erase" the lineart -- since it was just going to be multiplied in the end anyway.

I'd like to color the lineart now.  Unfortunately, the white on that layer is extremely uncooperative.  I've tried:

1) isolating the black with the background eraser.

2) isolating the black by loading the channel as a selection, then filling in the lineart on a new layer.

Neither one was effective enough to be the answer I need.  Are there any other good methods I can try to make the multiply effect WYSIWYG so I can clipping-mask color down onto the lineart itself?

Alternately, is there any good way to color the lines as they are without ruining the transparency of the white in the multiplied layer?

I use Adobe CS5 extended.

Comment: why not merge the layer down?

Comment: @Rohawk – I think you're on the right track with your second method (loading the channel as a selection), which is definitely what I would do. Can you elaborate on why it didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Try applying a `gradient map` layer style on the multiply layer. That way, if you map the white to stay white, you can map the black to your desired colour.

Another way to achieve a similar effect is to revert the layer to 'normal' opacity and play with the blending settings in the `Layer Style` window:

[image: blend if settings on this layer]

Drag the top bar's right indicator a bit to the left, and your white should disappear. If you <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>click & drag</kbd> the indicator to the left, it will split in two, indicating a smooth transition effect to take your anti-aliasing into account.

Using these, you can eliminate the white manually, without the need for multiplying. This has the added advantage that your colour stays opaque.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the blending style modifies the appearance of the layer but doesn't alter the presence of the white, and coloring down on top still goes outside the lineart.  Thank you for the answer, though! I'll try the gradient map now.

Comment: eh, then I must have misunderstood your initial setup. Do you have a 'shot?